# Show or hide featues by zoom level and importance

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Using arcgis for JS 4.24 `MapView`.

I have a feature layer with features of different importance to the user. The importance is defined in an attribute of the feature. What I want to achieve is, that less important features only show on a certain zoom level.

What I tried so far:

- Clustering: is not what I want since it is grouping on occurrences not importance.
- Unique Value Renderer: Does not seem to support visibility by zoom level but is otherwise exactly what I would use.
- Setting the min-max visibility: This applies to all features and cannot be configured by attribute value.

What did I miss? Any other ways to apply custom styles to feature layers?

Answer (score 1):

I guess a simple solution would be to create as many `FeatureLayer` instances as importances you have. In each of this instances you set,

1. `definitionExpression` to the importance level,
2. `maxScale` and `minScale` to constraint the visibility

This solution would work if the number of importance levels are "reasonable" (let say, less than 10 or so, you will have to test it).

Another solution would be to listen for scale changes in the map view (could be the `updating` event), and then apply a filter (could be `definitionExpression` again) with the correspondent importance. With this you do not need to have many instances of the same service.

*EDIT*

The reason for using `updating`, is to avoid doing stuff while the view is changing, something like this,

```
view.watch("updating", function (value) {
    if (!value) {
        // now is the moment to check view properties
        // for example
        if (view.scale < MIN_SCALE) {
            doSomething();
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: OK so I found this [Example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/event-explorer/) to watch properties on `MapView` to use instead of an `updating` event.

Comment: Take a look at the edit on the answer, if you listen directly to some properties this could change many times before "stabilize"

Comment: I now watch the `scale` property. If it crosses the min scale I change the renderer to one that shows or hides the unimportant features. It works but I think that performance could be better.

Comment: Changing the renderer (instead of definitionExpression) should usually perform better...   See this sample - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-heatmap-scale/

Comment: @BjornSvensson, that seems like a nice solution